# Recuperar projeto(aplicativo) instalado no Iphone - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app

Eu tenho um projeto que tava funcionando e eu instalei no Iphone(para testar) e agora eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer o caminho inverso e trazer esse projeto de volta pro Mac(XCode) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível. Ao compilar o projeto, o XCode gera um arquivo .ipa contendo o código compilado (executável) juntamente com os recursos (imagens, plists, etc).
O máximo que você consegue é extrair o ipa como zip e acessar esses recursos, mas de maneira nenhuma obterá um projeto do XCode de volta.